# How to pass the value of parameter from one to another function

Tags: c#

Please Help me to use the value of  "max value" in another function

public int maxvalue;

```
public void Levelchoose(int maxvalue){    ***//The parameter***
    Application.LoadLevel ("Game");
}

void NextGuess(){

    //guess = (max + min) / 2;
    guess= Random.Range(min , max + 1);
    text.text = "Is the number greater or lower than "+guess.ToString ()+" ?";
    maxvalue = maxvalue - 1; ***//i want the parameter value right here***
    print (maxvalue);
    if (maxvalue<=0){
        Application.LoadLevel("Win");
}
```

Comment: from where NextGuess get called ??

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do it:

1. Define maxValue as a global class level variable. Assign the value in Levelchoose to that global variable then it will be available in all other methods.
2. Change signature of NextGuess to include a parameter

   ```
   void NextGuess(int maxValue)
   ```

Then, pass the value from which ever calling method.

**New code as per suggestion 1.**

```
class MyGame
{
    public int MaxValue;

    public void Levelchoose(int maxvalue){    
        Application.LoadLevel ("Game");
        MaxValue = maxvalue;
    }

    void NextGuess(){

        //guess = (max + min) / 2;
        guess= Random.Range(min , max + 1);
        text.text = "Is the number greater or lower than "+guess.ToString ()+" ?";
        MaxValue = MaxValue - 1; ***//i want the parameter value right here***
        print (MaxValue);
        if (MaxValue<=0){
            Application.LoadLevel("Win");
    }
}
```